# Unable to debug Spring Boot application in Intellij Idea - FileNotFoundException (oraclepki.jar)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug an application on IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Community Edition) and I get this exception with the control pointing to URLClassPath.class in the editor. This is the file which is missing:

```
.../.m2/repository/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc8/21.1.0.0/oraclepki.jar
```

I have tried downloading individual JARs(`like for oraclepki.jar above`) and putting them in the correct location but it's like a recursive hell which is never ending.

As soon as I do that for one JAR file, another FileNotFoundException for a different JAR file pops up and I need to do searching, downloading and placing the JAR file in the correct location.

Strangely, I am able to run the application properly without any sort of problem. I have googled and searched for this but I am not able to understand why this is happening??? All my maven dependencies have properly been download and I am able to do a `mvn clean install` without any error.

Edit: I tried invalidate cache and restart option and even reinstalled Intellij!

---

FYI, IntelliJ version information:

Build #IC-203.7148.57, built on January 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1957M
Cores: 8
Registry: scala.erase.compiler.process.jdk.once=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.markskelton.one-dark-theme, org.intellij.scala, io.nimbly.tzatziki

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate IntelliJ cache and restart? This happens from time to time, specially if you have several projects.(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html)

Comment: Yes I tried that option and even reinstalled the IDE

Comment: Try to delete you .m2 folder, and start IntelliJ with a fresh home directory (change idea.properties file on bin folder: idea.system.path and idea.config.path for example). Also try to fetch a newer intelliJ and install it from scratch (instead of the one you have 2020.3.2)

Comment: What Run/Debug Configuration do you use to run and debug? Also - you can see and compare the full classpath the IDE constructs in the Run and Debug tool window when you run the app.

Comment: I use the green play icon available on the Main class file marked with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: @pringi ... tried all steps and now I'm getting FileNotFoundException for file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_301/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar

Comment: What jdk are you using in the project? Try using Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK to see if the problem continues. Use JDK not JRE.

Comment: Using Oracle's JDK. Java 1.8.301

Comment: Are you trying to connect to Autonomous Database? You can also use the 'ojdbc8-production' as shown in the page (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html) to download all the required jars along with JDBC driver.